# How to run a python script using an anaconda virtual environment on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda

I am trying to get some code working on mac and to do that I have been using an anaconda virtual environment. I have all of the dependencies loaded as well as my script, but I don't know how to execute my file in the virtual environment on mac. The python file is on my desktop so please let me know how to configure the path if I need to. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a terminal open and are in your virtual environment then simply invoking the script should run it in your environment.